# Can I do something like this in React inside a component?

Tags: reactjs

Can I do something like this in React inside a component? I am quite sure that I can but still do not know how exactly. What I want is to set post.summary to null or empty and I also need an else case like if it is not team_member value should be post.summary.

```
<my_component
value={post.summary = post.type === "team_member" ? "null" : "null"}
/>
```

Thank you in advance!

Cheers

Comment: What exactly do you want to do

Comment: In that case, why are you setting it inside the prop?
Is your question something like, if post.type === "team_member", you wanna set post.summary to empty?

If yes, what is post? A variable in your component?
When do you want to set it? After render? Before render?

If you want to set a varialble at certain point of time, you should use React Lifecycle methods. 

I can guide you once you provide more information.

Comment: `<MyComponent
postSummary={post.type === "team_member" ? null : post.summary} />` ?  ... and use `props.postSummary` for conditional rendering ?

Comment: I need something like this: value={post.summary={ post.type === "team_member" ? null : post.summary}}

Answer (score 1):

If you are more specific about your requirements, we can address it accordingly.

Howerver,

***If you want to pass some value as prop after evaluating a condition, you can.***

```
<Component
   value={condition === 1 ? "Yes" : "No"}
/>
```

> The meaning here is, if the condition is satisfied, value prop will be "Yes" else "No".

***If you want to conditionally put some content in your component.
Sure, you can.***

> Solution 1

```
<Component>
    {condition === 1 ? <div>Yes</div> : <div>Nope</div>}
</Component>
```

> Solution 2

```
<Component>
    {condition === 1 ? "Yes" : "Nope"}
</Component>
```

Solution 1 demonstrates that you can put another component or html tag
Solution 2 says that it can be a simple string too.

Hope it helps :)

Cheers,
Kruthika

Comment: Hi Kruthika, thank you for your quick response! Well, what I need is to set value to post.summery if post.type not equals team_member. If it equals, post.summery should be null.

Comment: Can you show some more code?
What is post in your code? A local objet? Or maybe a class variable?

Comment: I need something like this:    value={post.summary={ post.type === "team_member" ? null : post.summary}}

Comment: See @AlexHorvath, we can pass some values to a component as props. The component can uses props throghout its lifecycle. Refer this to get a good understanding: https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/introduction.html

Comment: **If post is a variable that is used in the component as a state variable**, you should use this.setState({post:{...post, summary = this.state.post.type === "team_member" ? null : this.post.summary}})

Comment: Or, **if post is a normal object in your component class and you wish to set it,** do it in a lifecycle method based on when you wanna update it in the component lifecycle.
https://reactjs.org/ refer the examples here

Comment: Unexpected token error for this:  this.setState({post:{...post, summary = this.state.post.type === "team_member" ? null : this.post.summary}})

Comment: @Alex, as i already mentioned please give more information or show your code of the component. Also, pls go through the articles that i mentioned.